# Floating point exception (core dumped) when calculating GCD

Tags: c, floating-point, coredump

I'm writing a program to reduce a fraction to the lowest term. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int m,x,n,gcd;
    printf("Enter a fraction: ");
    scanf("%d/%d",&n,&m);

    if(m==0)printf("Error");
    else
        for(;;){
           x=m%n;
           if(x==0){
              gcd=n;
              m/=gcd;
              n/=gcd;
              printf("In lowest terms: %d/%d",n,m);
            }else
                m=n;
                n=x;
         }

    return 0;
}
```

I use Euclid's algorithm to calculate the GCD. When executed, it reports

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Floating-point exceptions usually occur when integers are divided by zero. So look out for `/` and ´%` operators and check for the case `n == 0`. You might want to check the return value of `scanf`, too. It should be 2.

Comment: In light of the comment above, I can't help but notice the indentation of the `n=x` line.  It looks as if you intended that to be part of the `else`, but it is not (you did not enclose multiple expressions in `{ }`).  In the case where `x==0`, then `n` will also be set to zero.

Answer (score 5):

You have fallen victim to block scope here:

```
if(x==0){
    // ...
}else
    m=n;
    n=x;
```

This will be executed as:

```
if(x==0){
    // ...
}else{
    m=n;
}
n=x;
```

That means when `x` is zero, then `n` gets set to zero at the end of the loop.  When you come around again to calculate `m % n`, you have a problem.  Or if for some reason that gives a value without crashing your program, then `gcd = n` will end up giving you *divide-by-zero* when you subsequently divide `m` and `n` by `gcd`.

If you want more than one statement to be part of the `else` branch, then you need to enclose them in braces as follows:

```
if(x==0){
    // ...
}else{
    m=n;
    n=x;
}
```

In fact, it's good practice to always use the braces, even when you only have one statement.  At my workplace this is even in our coding standards, and part of the code review process.

Comment: Yes @paddy. I forgot to use braces so the result was all of mess. But actually my code was wrong. I had to check it again.

Answer (score 0):

@paddy 
Yes, I dint't see it through. Anyway my code has been flawed from the beginning. I use `for(;;)` to create loop but I tell it to stop at `else`. It is completely flawed because the loop will execute again and create an infinte loop. Additional, I intended to assign `gcd` to `n`, but before that `n` was assigned to `x` (that case,after `else`, the loop executed). Therefore if `x` is `0` then `m/=gcd` and `n/=gcd` may have caused `core dumped`. This is a stupid code that I shouldn't have asked. So I thought again and rewrote the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int m,x,n,gcd;
    int M,N;

    printf("Enter a fraction: ");
    scanf("%d/%d",&n,&m);
    M = m;
    N = n;

     if(m==0)printf("Error");
        else
        do{
           x=m%n;
           m=n;
           n=x;
             }while(x!=0);
    gcd=m;
    M/=gcd;
    N/=gcd;

    printf("In lowest terms: %d/%d\n",N,M);

    return 0;
}
```

Because after the `loop`, `m` and `n` has been modified so `m/=gcd` and `n/=gcd` can't return accurate result. So I assign `n` to `N`,`m` to `M` so that the value I entered won't change. Assigning `gcd` to `m` is a bit tricky, but it's not wrong because before that `m` was assign to `n`. so I think this trick would have same effect. I use `do while` loop because I can set the "termination point", so there will be no `infinite loop`.